Is there a way to make the thumb of a slider overflow without letting its shadow overflow?
So I've been working on customizing range sliders for a website I'm making. The only way I know how to add a different color for both sides of the slider is to add a shadow to the thumb and then hide overflow. however, I wanted to make the thumb bigger than the bar, but I can't do that without turning off overflow, which which let the shadow go outside of the box.
I tried turning the overflow off for only the thumb, and turning overflow on for only the shadow, but neither works. below is what my code looks like.
HTML:
<div class="slider">
    <input type="range" class="customRange" id="rangeInput1" name="rangeInput1" min="0" max="100" value="50"
    oninput="amount1.value=rangeInput1.value">
    <output id="amount1" name="amount1" for="rangeInput1">50</output>

CSS:
.customRange {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #F998F6;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}



.customRange::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #92008D;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: -210px 0 0 200px #DD00D6;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 0;
}

Maybe there's another way to add two different colors for the different sides, because then I could turn on overflow, but I just have no idea.

You can achieve this with bit of JavaScript. For this you have to remove the shadow method and also you can you gradients to fill different parts of the slide bar.
You can add gradient to your css like this,
.customRange {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #DD00D6 50%, #F998F6 50%); 
  outline: none;
  transition: background 0.3s;
}

.customRange::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #92008D;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px; 
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  }

.customRange::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
}

.customRange::-moz-range-track {
  background: transparent;
}

.customRange::-ms-track {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

.customRange:active {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #DD00D6 var(--value), #F998F6 var(--value));
}

and after adding this styles, you need to add a JS function that make the background gradient change as the slider is moving.
const rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeInput1");
const updateBackground = () => {
  const value = rangeInput.value;
  rangeInput.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #DD00D6 ${value}%, #F998F6 ${value}%)`;
};

rangeInput.addEventListener('input', updateBackground);

this way you can change the size of thumb without dealing with overflow.

I put all that code in and it isn't working. It does let the thumb overflow but what happens is that every time I click the thumb, the slider goes transparent, and then no matter where the thumb is when I let go, the two colors are still in the middle of the slider.

If the slider goes transparent, you can overcome with removing
"  .customRange:active " style

that removed the transparency problem but the different colors don't move when I drag the slider. when I run the code and the slider is in the middle the colors look correct, but when I drag the slider the colors stay right in the middle.
